# Looping array and adding, finding same ID's in all rows and columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Looping array and adding, finding same ID's in all rows and columns.

my table

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| StdID | day1S1 | day1S2 | day1S3 | day2S1 | day2S2 | day2S3 | day3S1 | day3S2 | day3S3 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     3 | NULL   |      1 |      0 |      1 |      1 |      0 | NULL   |      1 |      1 |
|     4 | 1      |      1 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 | NULL   |      1 |      1 |
|     3 | 1      |      0 |      0 |      1 |      1 |      0 | 1      |      1 |      1 |
|     3 | NULL   |      1 |      0 |      1 |      1 |      0 | NULL   |      0 |      0 |
|     4 | 0      |      1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |      0 | NULL   |      0 |      0 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I am using the following code

```
$stu_leave          = "SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE StdID = '3' ";
$stu_leave_result   = $conn->query($stu_leave);

while($stu_leave_result_fetch   = $stu_leave_result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $array = array("$day1S1","$day1S2","$day1S3","$day2S1","$day2S2","$day2S3","$day3S1","$day3S2","$day3S3");

    $counts = array_count_values($array);
    echo $counts['1']."<br>";
    echo $counts['0'];
}
```

Here is my output

```
5 6 3 
2 3 4
```

I would like to get the result as

```
14 (add all 5 + 6 + 3).
9
```

Please help me someone.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. could you tell more about that?

Comment: Where do `$day1S1` and all those other variables come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_walk, array_count_values and array_sum to achieve your requirement

```
$result = [];
array_walk($a, function ($item) use (&$result) {
    $item = array_filter($item, function ($var) {
        // removing null values
        return ($var !== null);
    });
    $result[] = array_count_values($item);
});

echo array_sum(array_column($result, 1))."<br/>";
echo array_sum(array_column($result, 0));
```

[array_sum](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) — Calculate the sum of values in an array
[array_walk](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array
[array_column](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array
[array_filter](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) — Filters elements of an array using a callback function

**Output**

```
14
9
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ea1fc4084bbf8af094249ea55ce0a7240fd8d29).

**EDIT**

Mapping to your code,

```
$result = [];
while($stu_leave_result_fetch   = $stu_leave_result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $array = array("$day1S1","$day1S2","$day1S3","$day2S1","$day2S2","$day2S3","$day3S1","$day3S2","$day3S3");
    $array = array_filter($array, function ($var) {
        // fetching null values
        return ($var !== null);
    });
    $result[] = array_count_values($array);
});
echo array_sum(array_column($result, 1))."<br/>";
echo array_sum(array_column($result, 0));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rahul. I was trying this from today morning. Thanks a lots. Perfect

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yours is as I requested. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just sum the values using `array_sum()`.

```php
while ($stu_leave_result_fetch = $stu_leave_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $counts = array_count_values($array);
    $sum = array_sum($counts);
    echo $sum."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. When I use this code, it shows sum of all rows ie 14 9 three times. Any chance to split it?

Comment: That means that you loop it three times. You perhaps want a `GROUP BY` in your query instead.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you only query the columns that you are actually interested in, the fetched array will only contain the data you want to sum.

You can then do a simple `array_sum()` on the returned row, making the code a lot simpler and easier to read.

```
$sql    = "SELECT day1S1, day1S2, day1S3, day2S1, 
                  day2S2, day2S3, day3S1, day3S2, day3S3 
            FROM tblname 
            WHERE StdID = '3'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{

    echo array_sum($row) . '<br>';
}
```